# What's going on? Can't set the location of my JLabel

Tags: java, jframe, jlabel

So i'm programming a little game and when i try to set a JLabel to x = 0 and y = 0
it appears in the middle of the JFrame.
Heres the code when i add it

```
for (int i = 0; i < btns.size(); i++){
                    Button btn = btns.get(i);
                    if (!components.contains(btn.getJLabel())){
                        frame.add(btn.getJLabel());
                        components.add(btn.getJLabel());
                    }
                    if (!btn.getJLabel().isVisible()) btn.getJLabel().setVisible(true);
                    btn.getJLabel().setText(btn.getText());
                }
```

And also i put a MouseListener in it so that when the mouse goes over the button it will turn red but when i hover over the JFrame it turns red

```
label.addMouseListener(new MouseListener(){

        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            onClick();
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
            Hover();
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
            out();
        }

        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }});
}
public void Hover(){
    label.setForeground(Color.RED);
}

public void out(){
    label.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
}
```

Here's the whole code of the main class:
    `
    public static JFrame frame;

```
public static double VERSION = 1.0;
public static int WIDTH = 800, HEIGHT = 700;
public static boolean editorMode = false;
public static boolean selectedTower = false;
public static boolean running = false;
public static boolean mouseOver = false;

public static Tower editorTower = null;
public static Tower selectTower = null;

public static ArrayList<Button> btns;
public static ArrayList<Tower> towers;
public static ArrayList<Component> components;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setTitle("MyLittleGame v"+VERSION);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.addMouseListener(new MouseListener(){

        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent arg0) {
            mouseOver = true;
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent arg0) {
            mouseOver = false;
        }

        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }});
    btns = new ArrayList<Button>();
    towers = new ArrayList<Tower>();
    components = new ArrayList<Component>();
    registerBtns();
    running = true;
    startGameLoop();
}

public static void registerBtns(){
    btns.add(new NewTowerBtn());
}

private static void startGameLoop(){
    new Thread(new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run() {
            int towerAdding = 0;
            while (running){
                int mouseX = 10;
                int mouseY = 10;
                if (mouseOver){
                    mouseX = (int) frame.getMousePosition().getX();
                    mouseY = (int) frame.getMousePosition().getY();
                }
                if (editorMode && editorTower != null){
                    editorTower.setXloc(mouseX);
                    editorTower.setYloc(mouseY);
                }
                for (int i = 0; i < towers.size(); i++){
                    Tower tower = towers.get(i);
                    if (!components.contains(tower.getLabel())){
                        frame.add(tower.getLabel());
                        components.add(tower.getLabel());
                    }
                    if (towerAdding >= 100) tower.grow();
                    if (!tower.getLabel().isVisible()) tower.getLabel().setVisible(true);
                    tower.getLabel().setText(tower.getWholeString());
                }
                for (int i = 0; i < btns.size(); i++){
                    Button btn = btns.get(i);
                    if (!components.contains(btn.getJLabel())){
                        frame.add(btn.getJLabel());
                        components.add(btn.getJLabel());
                    }
                    if (!btn.getJLabel().isVisible()) btn.getJLabel().setVisible(true);
                    btn.getJLabel().setText(btn.getText());
                }
                if (towerAdding >= 100) towerAdding = 0;
                towerAdding++;
                System.out.println("Went through");
            }
        }}).start();
}`
```

Also when i tred to add a normal JLabel with the location x = 0 and y = 0 too it put it in the middle again?
Thank you.

Comment: One doesn't normally set the position of components on a JFrame (or JPanel) by using absolute position, and if you do, the layout has to be set to null. Look at a tutorial on layout managers in Swing; I would guess your JLabel is being added to the CENTER of the BorderLayout that is JFrame's default layout manager.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As arcy said, if you are trying to use [absolute positioning](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/none.html) you have to change your frame's layout to null

```
frame.setLayout(null);
```

You can also check how to use other layout managers [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html).

Comment: Did you set the bounds of your JLabel, by using `setBounds(x, y, width, height)`

Comment: Yes `label.setBounds(x, y, width, height);`

Comment: Uhm you are adding directly the label to the frame (and not the content pane), try `frame.setLayout(null);`.